# magento : Your password reset link has expired

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an issue when I click on the reset password link url :

I have four website in one magento platform like : domain.com, domain.com/us/ domain.com/it/ domain.com/ca/

On my main site (domain.com) when I click on forgot password I get the email with reset password link . When I click on the reset password link I am successfully redirected to reset password url .

But when I follow same process with my other sites like domain.com/us , I am getting the forgot password email but when I click on the reset password link I am redirect on the Forgot password link (domain.com/us/customer/account/forgotpassword/) instead of reset password link and I am getting an error message stating "Your password reset link has expired".

Answer (score 0):

Update app/design/frontend/your_theme_package/your_theme_name/layout/customer.xml file for your theme as shown in diff below (your_theme_package/your_theme_name is the name of your theme):

```
 *   Find <customer_account_resetpassword translate="label"> replaced by   <customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
       <label>Reset a Password</label>

    <reference name="content">

   *  find            <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    replaced by           <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
             </reference>

  *   find    </customer_account_resetpassword>
     replaced    </customer_account_changeforgotten>
```